# Cannot increment variable inside function

Tags: r

I am simply trying to increment this variable inside this function :

```
 process = function(line){
  if(exists("Counter")== FALSE){Counter <- 0}
  
  input <- str_split(line,',')
  output <- paste("tree", toString(Counter))
  
  Counter <- arbreCounter + 1
  setglobal(input,output)
  
  print(Counter)
}
```

When i run through the function i only get :

```
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to give a good answer but here's some ideas.

1. Nowhere in the function do you actually increment `Counter`. It looks like you're using `arbreCounter` to do it but I have no idea the value or scope of `arbreCounter`.
2. `Counter` appears to be a locally-scoped variable (it is created when the systems enters the function and is destroyed when the function terminates) so `exists("Counter")` probably always returns `FALSE`.